# Element-wise "multiplication" of two lists with different type

Tags: python, list

How to perform element wise "multiplication" between a list of strings and a list of boolean values?

For example if i have the following lists :

```
list_1=['A','B','C','D']

list_2=[True,False,True,False]
```

Expected output is :

```
list_output==['A','','C','']
```

Wherever there is True the string are maintained, and wherever there is False the string are
replaced by empty string `('')`

Answer (score 3):

You can actually directly multiply corresponding elements after zipping the two lists since `True` is equivalent to `1` and `False` to `0`. Multiplying a string by an integer repeats it that number of times.

```py
res = [x * y for x, y in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyezuCTeUMFWIVrdUV1H3QmInYHYRT2WCyxlBJIKKSpN1XFLzClO1UEwY7mKUotBshUKWgqVCmn5RQoVOkBGZp5CVWaBBsRgHQWIKZqxXAVFmXklGkA9mv//AwA)

Answer (score 2):

```
from operator import mul

list_output = [*map(mul, list_1, list_2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd zip the two lists and then use a list comprehension to generate the desired output:

```py
list_output = [i[0] if i[1] else '' for i in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

Comment: use iterable unpacking: `[letter if condition else '' for letter, condition in zip(list_1, list_2)]`

Comment: Since `'A' * 0 == ''` and False is 0 and True is 1, this works: `list_output = [a*b for a,b in zip(list_1, list_2)]`

Answer (score 1):

```py
list_1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
list_2 = [True, False, True, False]

list_output = [x if y else '' for x, y in zip(list_1, list_2)]

print(list_output) # Output: ['A', '', 'C', '']
```